# Designing a tournament bracket - not fitting together well

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to design the visuals of a tournament bracket but it's not slotting together well!!

The CSS is as follows:

```
#tournament-holder{
width:708px;
padding:20px 0 20px 15px;
float:left;
}
.vertical-holder{
width:100px;
padding-right:15px;
float:left;
}
.horizontal-holder1{
width:98px;
height:98px;
margin-bottom:15px;
border:1px solid #bdbdbd;
float:left;
}
.horizontal-holder2{
width:98px;
height:98px;
margin:57.5px 0 72.5px 0;
border:1px solid #bdbdbd;
float:left;
}
.horizontal-holder3{
width:98px;
height:98px;
margin:172.5px 0 187.5px 0;
border:1px solid #bdbdbd;
float:left;
}
.horizontal-holder4{
width:98px;
height:98px;
margin:402.5px 0 417.5px 0;
border:1px solid #bdbdbd;
float:left;
}
.horizontal-holder5{
width:98px;
height:98px;
margin:862.5px 0 877.5px 0;
border:1px solid #bdbdbd;
float:left;
}
.horizontal-holder6{
width:98px;
height:98px;
margin:1782.5px 0 1797.5px 0;
border:1px solid #bdbdbd;
float:left;
}
.white-holder{
width:98px;
height:49px;
background-color:white;
float:left;
}
.yellow-holder{
width:98px;
height:49px;
background-color:#FFF8DC;
float:left;
}
.player-holder{
width:70px;
height:49px;
float:left;
}
.score-holder{
width:28px;
height:49px;
float:left;
}
```

Now for the HTML:

```
<div id="tournament-holder">
            <div class="vertical-holder">
                <?php
                $q = "SELECT u.username, p.position FROM ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_PLAYERS." p
                      INNER JOIN ".TBL_USERS." u ON p.userid = u.id
                      WHERE p.tourid = '$tour_id' ORDER BY position";
                $result = $database->query($q);
                $i = 1;
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    extract($row);
                    if($i&1){
                        ?>
                        <div class="horizontal-holder1">
                            <div class="white-holder">
                                <div class="player-holder">
                                    <? echo "$username"; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="score-holder">
                                    0
                                <div>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else{
                        ?>
                            <div class="yellow-holder">
                                <div class="player-holder">
                                    <? echo "$username"; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="score-holder">
                                    0
                                <div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>
            </div>

            <?php
            //subsequent rounds

            for($i=1; $i <= $rounds; $i++)
            {
                $j = $i + 1; //this is to generate the correct horizontal holder
                $k = 1; //this is the order of the players - to check if they are odd or even as they come out.
                $players = $players / 2;
                $q = "SELECT u.username, r.position FROM ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_ROUNDS." r
                      INNER JOIN ".TBL_USERS." u ON u.id = r.winner
                      WHERE tourid = '$tour_id' && round = '$i' ORDER BY position";
                $result = $database->query($q);
                ?>
                <div class="vertical-holder">
                    <?php
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    extract($row);
                        if($k&1){
                            ?>
                            <div class="horizontal-holder<?php echo $j; ?>">
                                <div class="white-holder">
                                    <div class="player-holder">
                                        <? echo "$username"; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="score-holder">
                                        0
                                    <div>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        else{
                            ?>
                                <div class="yellow-holder">
                                    <div class="player-holder">
                                        <? echo "$username"; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="score-holder">
                                        0
                                    <div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        $k++;
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

The following is a link to what the bracket is currently rendering as:

[Current Bracket problem](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/screenshot20120110at142.png/)

Clearly, something isn't lining up correctly.

The idea of the bracket is that 'tournament-holder' will hold the overall bracket. Each round will have a 'vertical-holder'...each vertical holder will a contain horizontal-holder for every 2 teams (1 fixture). The 6 different horizontal holders are for different spacings between fixtures as the tournament goes further and further. In each horizontal holder, there will be a yellow or white holder. Both are the same, just different background colours. Inside each of these will be a player and score holder.

I know it's quite a complex question to answer but can answer solve this?
I'm having major problems, just can't work it out.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done several graphics like these and used to own a web sports team/league management software. For this to work, you need to first prepare your structure in memory and not just query and loop.

```
$structure = array();
$data = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM standings WHERE blablabla');
while($datarow = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){

    //Evaluate the round in the first level and the match in second
    $round = $datarow['round'];
    $matchid = $datarow['round'];
    $homeorvisitor = ($datarow['ishome'] ? 'home' : 'visitor');
    $structure[$round][$mathid][$homeorvisitor] = $datarow;   

}
```

This would create you a structure where you find your matches and each opponents for each match grouped together in rounds.

Then, using a simple looping logic, you can create a table that contains each round and in each table, you create a div that shows a matchup. I like using tables for that but if you are good enough with CSS, go at it with CSS. I tried using divs here and it should output fine with simple CSS.

```
foreach($structure as $roundkey => $round){

    ?><div id="round<?php echo $roundkey; ?>" class="round"><?php

        foreach($round as $matchid => $match){

            ?><div id="match<?php echo $matchid; ?>" class="match round<?php echo $roundkey; ?>"><?php

                //Output your match box content here

            ?></div><?php

        }

    ?></div><?php

}
```

This should output you

```
<div id="round1" class="round">
    <div id="match1" class="match round1">
    </div>
    <div id="match2" class="match round1">
    </div>
    <div id="match3" class="match round1">
    </div>
    <div id="match4" class="match round1">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="round2" class="round">
    <div id="match5" class="match round2">
    </div>
    <div id="match6" class="match round2">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="round3" class="round">
    <div id="match7" class="match round3">
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS i propose is to make rounds a certain width, floating side by side and each match would take a specific height and width depending on the round# associated with it. So that way you will be able to make one match in round1 smaller than a match in round2 (take twice the height to center it.

Does that all make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the response, just before reading it, I realised why mine isn't displaying correctly. It's because the if else statement is causing the div tag to be closed at the wrong stage which causes chaos. So I decided to use an array. Then looking at what you wrote, to an extent you have done just that. The main difference is you are using an array and I will take that on board and merge that into my solution. Hopefully it will find some structure for me! Thanks a lot for the answer, really helpful. I'll post my results :)